# How do i get all text content from an ajax webpage

Tags: java, ajax, parsing, jsoup

How do i get all text content from this ajax webpage using the jsoup library.

I've tried this so far:

```
    String result="";
    Document doc=JSoup.connect("http://www.islamicuniversity.edu.in/Descrip?     date=SELID1").get();
    Elements allElements=doc.select("#latest_header");
    for(Element looper:allElements){
    result=looper.text();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

we can make ajax xmlhttp request to wepage as follows

```
function getAjaxData() {
  var url = "";
  var parameters ="";
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        var ajaxText = xmlhttp.responseText
    };
};
xmlhttp.open("POST",url+"?"+parameters,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: But i will have to write that code in the <script> tag of html. I need to do that in Java only. To be specific , i need to do that in an Android app

Answer (score 0):

By Jsoup 1.7.2

```
    String result="";
    Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.islamicuniversity.edu.in/Descrip?date=SELID1").get();
    Elements allElements=doc.select("#latest_header");
    for(Element looper:allElements){
        result=looper.text();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```